# JDBC ResultSet get column from different tables

Tags: jdbc

i wan to retrieve data from query involving many tables.
i have a query as follows

```java
    String sql = "SELECT "
            + "s.Food_ID AS 'Sales_FoodID', "
            + "f.Food_Name AS 'foodName' "
            + "FROM Ordering o, Sales s, Food f"
            + " WHERE o.Table_No = " + tableNo + ""
            + " AND o.Paid = '" + NOT_PAID + "'"
            + " AND s.Order_ID = o.Order_ID"
            + " AND f.Food_ID = s.Food_ID;";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

no error were found when i run the program, but after i add this line to get a table's column data:

```java
    String orderID = resultSet.getString("foodName");
```

i'm given this error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Column not found
```

anyone know why?

Comment: set a breakpoint on `String orderID = resultSet.getString("foodName");` and see what the `resultSet` contains.

Comment: @ZnArK This happens because ResultSet.getString(String) fetches for the column by its name and not by its alias/label. This is actually the answer for the question "anyone know why?", but since it won't solve the problem, I'll leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `next()` method.

You should know that `ResultSet` is implicitly positioned on position before first row so you need to call next to get current position and if is valid, it returns `true`, else returns `false` (cursor is positioned after the last row).

```
rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
   String orderID = rs.getString(2);
}
```

**Note:** You can use also `rs.getString(<columnName>)` but in case when you know how your statement looks i recommend to you use index instead of columnName.

Answer (score 0):

After calling the `resultSet.executeQuery()` you need to call the `next()` to pulling the records from db

after that you can call  `setXxx()` provided by Java API