# How to get a column by alias/label from Java's ResultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Suppose I have a SP which does `SELECT a as b FROM example_table` at the end.

When I do

```java
// Some magical code goes here
ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.printLn(rs.getString("b"));
}
// Some magical code goes here
```

I get an error telling me that the column does not exist, however when I change my code for `rs.getString("a")`, It will execute correctly. This seems to be because the `getString(String)` fetches for the column by its name, not by its alias/label.

How can I tell the ResultSet to fetch the column by label/alias, not by its name.

PS: I found a similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211514/jdbc-resultset-get-column-from-different-tables)

Comment: It has worked for me in the past. I suspect it is a JDBC driver issue. Which one are you using?

Comment: Also, looks like you are invoking a procedure and not an SQL!

Comment: @adarshr Yes, it is an SP (updated my question) And the driver is jconn3.jar Version: 6.0 Build (25828)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alper was on the money.

They changed the driver and added a connection property GET_COLUMN_LABEL_FOR_NAME that you need to set to "true".  I thought it was only for resultSetMetaData, but apparently not so much...

It's bizarre, but try it.

Reference in [Sybooks](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0605/html/prjdbc/prjdbc14.htm)

Sybase Newsgroup [Article](http://sdn.doradus.de/conversation/380036/)

Comment: Ok, but just to put a note here, it may be a good idea to check that properties object/file/thingy, because it was named differently in my version

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is related but in MySQL there is a similar problem which you can avert by adding `?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true` to the end of the connection string. [Check this link for details](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/05/javasqlsqlexception-column-name-not.html)

[The link of an official explanation for the same case](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31406): Here it says, until the version 5.0.x the default value was set to `true`  but after the version 5.1 the default value was set `false`. You can also check the other parameters for the configuration string [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)